# What does the phrase "soar off ramps" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Here is a sentence from a game app's description:

> In the game, you **soar off ramps** to beat competitors to the finish
>   line.

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase **soar off ramps** here. How would you explain the same idea in different words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning seems to be literal. For example, think of ski jumping:

> [image]
>
> <sup>[Ski Jumper Sarah Hendrickson Takes Flight on the Sleeping Giant](https://youtu.be/nIH01DgMOnI)</sup>

In this picture, the skier is soaring off a ramp. "Soaring" is essentially synonymous with "gliding"; the skier will be in the air for at least a second and travel quite some distance. "Off" tells us that the skier used the ramp to help her jump. A "ramp" is essentially a slope; in this image it is the large structure in the background, but other sports use ramps that [look different](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1435&bih=724&tbm=isch&sa=1&ei=lEbbXM-zOIe4gge9yL2ADQ&q=bmx+ramps&gs_l=img.).